# white spaces after using unite() from tplyr in R

Tags: r, dplyr, whitespace

So the problem I have is that I am using unite() to concatenate some variables and leave a "." in-between, the problem is that it also leaves a white space before the "." For example.

```
 Col1        Col2          Col3            Col4      Col5
DAIRY     *Unassigned   *Unassigned      UNKNOWN   90-10-257
DAIRY     *Unassigned   *Unassigned      UNKNOWN   90-10-257
DAIRY      CHEESES       Cottage Cheese  MED       90-1025-1078
```

So I use:

```
united <- data%>%unite(id,colnames,sep=".")
```

And in the results I get the "." but also a white space before, how can I avoid this? Thank you.

```
id    
DAIRY .*Unassigned.*Unassigned .UNKNOWN .90-10-257    
DAIRY .*Unassigned.*Unassigned .UNKNOWN .90-10-257    
DAIRY .CHEESES.Cottage Cheese .MED .90-1025-1078
```

Comment: Are you sure there is no white space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ycw was right, there were white spaces in the data. I used strip.white property when reading the data to fix it.

```
data <- read.csv("data.csv",header = TRUE,strip.white = TRUE)
```

That did it. Thank you!